# C#.Net DocuSign Signature Position

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, docusignapi

My query regarding the signature position.
**Current approach** : now we are placing signature in document using appearance tag. I am adding data in reason tag and bind this with appearance tag and also mention position using "X" and "Y" tag.
**Required Change** : Need to add reason tag (user information) inside signature box. Our client is providing document with signature box in multiple places on same document (using DocuSign). Instead of using appearance tag I need to add reason tag (user information) inside signature box. I am sharing code portion here .

```
using RestSharp;
using System;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace DSARestCsharpSample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String baseURL ​​​​​= "https://prime-dsa-devctr.docusign.net:8081%22;
            String resourcePath = "sapiws/v1/digital_signature";
            String apiUrl = baseURL + "/" + resourcePath;
            var client = new RestClient(apiUrl);

            var request = new RestRequest(Method.PUT);
            request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
            request.AddHeader("authorization", "Basic " + DSABasicAuthorizationString("{dsa-user-name}", "{dsa-user-password}"));
            // "digital_signature" request body as Json formated String (use JavaScriptSerializer or Newtonsoft.Json to build from object) 
            String DigSigRequestBody =  
                "{ \"CreateAndSignField\" : " + //structure name specifies the operation / function
                    "{   \"file\": " + "\"" + File2Base64String("c:\\tmp\\PurchaseOrder.pdf") + "\", " +
                        "\"fileType\": \"PDF\", " +
                            "\"x\": \"" + DOCUSIGN_X + "\", " +
                            "\"y\": \"" + DOCUSIGN_Y + "\", " +
                            "\"width\": \"187\", " +
                            "\"height\": \"38\", " +
                            "\"page\": \"1\", " +
                            "\"timeFormat\": \"h:mm:ss\", " +
                            "\"dateFormat\": \"dd/MM/yyyy\", " +                    
                             "\"appearance\": \"100\", " +
                             "\"SigFieldName\": \"Employee\", " +
                              "\"Reason\": \"" + REASON + "\", " +
                               "\"Flags\": \"0\", " +
                                 "\"RetFileMode\": \"0\", " +
                                   "\"RetSigFieldMode\": \"0\", " +
                                   "\"appearance\": [\"Reason\", \"TIME\"]" +
                    "}" +
                "}";
            request.AddParameter("application/json", DigSigRequestBody, ParameterType.RequestBody);

            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

            JObject joResponse = JObject.Parse(response.Content);

            Base64String2Path(joResponse["signedFile"].Value<string>(), "c:\\tmp\\PurchaseOrder.DSA-REST-SIGNED.pdf");
        }

        private static void Base64String2Path(string Base64String, string FilePath)
        {
            Byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(Base64String);
            File.WriteAllBytes(FilePath, bytes);
        }

        private static String File2Base64String(String FilePath)
        {
            Byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(FilePath);
            String fileB64Data = System.Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
            return fileB64Data;
        }

        private static String DSABasicAuthorizationString(String username, string password)
        {
            var DSABasicAuthorizationBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(username+":"+password);
            return System.Convert.ToBase64String(DSABasicAuthorizationBytes);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're using the DocuSign Signature Appliance, yes?

Comment: **YES** @LarryK

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the Title field for "additional information".
The reason field has a meaning in PDF and it is not recommended for using it to use it as a general data information container.